# Reflection optimization

Tags: c#, performance, .net, reflection

In a web application I'm working on I have a class that Map objects to other (different) objects. It is implemented with something like:

```
public interface IMapper
{
    object Map<T>(T item);
}

public class Mapper
{
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Delegate> cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Delegate>();

    public Mapper()
    {
        // dependencies are injected in the constructor
        // not shown here for simplicity
    }

    public object Map<T>(T item)
    {
        if (cache.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
            return (cache[typeof(T)] as Func<T, object>)(item);

        var method = typeof(Mapper).GetMethod("Map", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new[] { typeof(T) }, null);

        var @delegate = (Func<T, object>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T, object>), this, method);
        cache.TryAdd(typeof(T), @delegate);

        return @delegate(item);

        // I'm trying not to use this 
        //return method.Invoke(this, new object[] { item });
    }

    public object Map(Guid item) { return new object(); }
}
```

In order to assess what *I believe* should be a performance gain (compared to the .Invoke() solution) I tried to generate ten million objects (tested with strings) and then I ran the mapper for all of them and printed out the time elapsed. The results are.

- Direct call: 1.67 s
- Reflection: 14.09 s
- Optimized Reflection: 2.62 s

which is not bad actually but I wonder if I'm testing this correctly.

Test code

```
 var guidList = new List<Guid>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            guidList.Add(Guid.NewGuid());
        }

        var mapper = new Mapper();

        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        var result = guidList.Select(_ => mapper.Map<Guid>(_)).ToList();
        sw.Stop();
```

(Obviously, when I tested the direct method call I changed the select lambda expression to `_ => mapper.Map(_)`)

Am I doing it right?

On a side note: I declared the ConcurrentDictionary as `ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Delegate>` and so I have to "cast" the delegate part like this `(cache[typeof(T)] as Func<T, object>)(item)` when I'm using it. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: This [blog post](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2008/08/09/making-reflection-fly-and-exploring-delegates/) by Jon Skeet may interest you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using a `ConcurrentDictionary` as a cache, and having to cast, you can use an embedded generic static class. The static construction is lazy and threadsafe by design. To make it work you have to create and open delegate (an instance method with no "`this`") for the mapper function:

```
public class Mapper
{
    public Mapper()
    {
        // dependencies are injected in the constructor
        // not shown here for simplicity
    }

    public object Map<T>(T item)
    {
        var mapper = MapperCache<T>.Map;
        return mapper(this, item);
    }

    // example methods
    public object Map(SomeObject item) { return new object(); }

    public object Map(SomeTotallyDifferentObject item) { return new object(); }

    public object Map(Guid item) { return new object(); }

    private static class MapperCache<T>
    {
        public static readonly Func<Mapper, T, object> Map;

        static MapperCache()
        {
            var mapMethod = typeof(Mapper).GetMethod("Map", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new[] { typeof(T) }, null);

                Map = mapMethod != null ? (Func<Mapper, T, object>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<Mapper, T, object>), mapMethod)
                                        : (mapper, item) => { throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(Mapper)} cannot map from {typeof(T).Name} to object"); };
        }
    }
}
```

The first time you reference the static property, `Map`, the `MapperCache<T>` for the given type `T` will be initialized. By setting up the delegate creation in the static constructor you guarantee that it will only run once for each `T`. If any exceptions are thrown in the static constructor the type will fail to load and cannot be used at runtime.

The same trick is used in [`System.Data.DataRowExtensions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowextensions(v=vs.110).aspx) ([source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Data.DataSetExtensions/R/9495b9cd327568a9.html)) to cache converters.

Comment: This approach makes you create **all** delegates ever used at the same time though.

Comment: @BrunoCosta they're created at first use for each type, not all at once.

Comment: Ah it uses a generic `MapperCache` class! Very clever with this use of generics :D! Even so could make the static constructor a bit tricky because you could have to check for the type of T but I don't think I would mind that

Answer (score 3):

First you are defining an interface `IMapper` but are not using it.

Your `method` will be null, if no matching method is available. `Delegate.CreateDelegate` will therefore throw an `ArgumentNullException`.

Converting to a `List` via `.ToList()` takes quite some time. `List` has a `.ForEach()` method. If you only want to test performance use:

```
sw.Start();
guidList.ForEach(_ => mapper.Map<Guid>(_));
sw.Stop();
```

Also you can use `dynamic`, which is faster than reflection (not what you asked, but still interesting):

```
public object Map<T>(T item)
{
    return Map((dynamic)item);
}
```

(The above code will result in an infinite loop and therefore a `StackOverflowException`, if the corresponding method is not implemented.)

**Edit**: As you are interested in this: Before calling `Map((dynamic)item)`, you should make sure, that the right method is available. Catching a `StackOverflowException` is impossible ([in this case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jaredpar/when-can-you-catch-a-stackoverflowexception)). You could do this by providing a default implementation

```
public object Map(object item)
{ ... }
```

Or you could use a `HashSet<Type>` with all implemented `Type`s and `throw` a `NotImplementedException` if `item.GetType()` is not in the `HashSet<Type>`.

Comment: The interface is used in other part of the programs, not very relevant here and removed all the validation code to make it simple. Your last part seems interesting, gonna check it out as soon as I can, thank you!

Comment: @Lennox - it's a handy way to get dynamic dispatch. I.e. the best `Map` method will be chosen at runtime rather than compile time.

Comment: Thanks Fabian, the dynamic solution is slightly faster than the cache solution and much much simpler.

Comment: You could also make `Map<T>` an explicit interface implementation, `object IMapper.Map<T>(T item)...`, then it won't be a candidate for the dynamic overload resolution.

Answer (score 2):

Looks OK. Did you avoid the usual benchmark error of running this under the debugger *or* in Debug mode?

You avoided another common error of having too short of a benchmark. Since your measurements are above 1sec all one-time costs such as JIT disappear in the noise.

You're also measuring the performance of `Select` and `ToList`. You can avoid that with a `for` loop.

You can avoid the delegate casting if you push the casting into the map method. All map methods must take `object` and cast their argument. That should be faster because casting generic types is, I think, rather slow.

You can go a little faster if you avoid `ConcurrentDictionary`. Ideally, you'd replace it with a custom hash table. `Dictionary` has some features in it that you don't need but that cost performance.

Comment: Is this stuff you picked up along the way? Where did you learn about these performance stats?

Comment: I measured timings while compiled in Debug but I believe it doesn't matter much since I'm interested in relative difference and not the absolute values. Same goes with select I believe. I need the concurrent dictionary because I'm using this in a multi thread application.  I didn't quite get the part about casting, would you care to expand a little more on that?